# Custom Button In Ribbon - SharePoint 2013

Tags: ribbon, custom-actions, dashboard-designer-2013

I need to create a custom action in SharePoint's ribbon so it will work on every list and library. I am creating such action using SP Designer but I can do it only for one particular list.

Is there any way to create such action using the SP Designer which will work in all site's lists and libraries? If not, please suggest another way of implementing such button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the references, however as I understood people there want to have the button on a specific list/library. I am looking for some solution to create a button which will work on every lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create that Button in the Master Page and use javascript/jquery to hide it for pages whose current page URL do not contain "/Lists" or "/Forms". In this way you can have your button for only lists and libraries.

Comment: It seems that the solution will help to solve the issue, however I can't find any option in SP Designer how to create the custom action for master page. The corresponding item appears only when I select a list.

Comment: you need to add your own HTML/aspx controls on the page..

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Will try to figure out. Thanks for directing :)